# Pattern matching : Matching a String with a pattern

Tags: java, regex, algorithm, pattern-matching, time-complexity

I was trying to match a pattern within a string. I am running out of ideas how to do this in Java with good time complexity.

> **No its not a simple regex matching (*but loved to be proved wrong*)**

What I am trying is,

**Pattern** : "1221" (Means 1 word repeat once, 2nd word repeat twice, last word is same as first word)

**Valid Input**: "aabbbbbbaa" (aa occurs at the beginning and at end, while middle portion is occupied by bbb repeating twice)

I tried the following approaches but failed miserably

- I tried to loop input with the pattern. But that did not solve the problem, although with more loops I can achieve it, but it increases the time complexity exponentially.
- Tried recursion and again no use.

What other approaches can I try?

I think Dynamic programming might be the answer, but I am not able to determine the terminating condition.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Add the code you've tried

Comment: I don't want the code, I can code myself. I just want the approach. Although I would love to have a sample. 

As I mentioned in my post, I post two of my approaches.

Comment: Sounds very close to [this](https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/130/).

Comment: Thanks for that. Yes it is similar, but my problem is a breakdown from a larger problem. Again looking for the approach

Comment: If it is similar then you're not explaining the problem properly. Example is a good thing but it cannot replace good definitions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simple regex, e.g.:

```
^(.+)(.+)\2\1$
```

It does exactly what u want:

[image]

Comment: are you sure this will work?  I don't think so. Pattern and input might change. Pattern can be 1111, 12341, 112, or anything

Comment: @Novice123, you can dynamically create regexes, I reckon. Regex I've provided is for `1221` pattern

Comment: ok thanks. I will try and accept the answer if it solves the answer. Thanks for the explanation

Comment: As you provided only `1221`, this answer is fit. Could you provide more examples for match ?

Comment: Let me try out the given solution. If that doesn't work, I will edit the question and provide more cases

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk: I checked your [regex here](https://regex101.com/r/sK2fJ8/3). How is first `(.+)` matching only `a`. Should it be consuming multiple characters after `a` and go on till end ?

Comment: @noob, ? This regex consists of two groups, in your example `a` falls into first group, and `bbb` into second. Then again, reference to group `2`, and `1`.

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk: I have used your regex in demo. My question is how is first group stopping at only `a` ? Since it's `(.+)` it should go on and consume everything till the end.

Comment: @noob, because regex is quite smart, isn't it? :)

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk: I got the trick ;-). It's backtracking and forced to match groups. Debugger reveals it all.

Comment: @noob, I appreciate this